# How can I get all the nodes from a level in a Nested set model?

Tags: sql, tree, avl-tree, nested-set-model

Is there an low-cost way of querying a table with a nested set model in order to get a collection of nodes from a specific level?

i.e. How can I get IEnumerable from my tree level n?
i.e. How can I get IEnumerable from my tree level n-1?

Thanks!

Comment: Which RDMS are you using?  Sample XML would also be helpful

Comment: Thanks @JohnCappelletti! I'm using MSSQL. Simple node structure with Id, Left, Right fields

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little more than you need, but it can be trimmed down.

The following TVF will parse virtually any XML structure and return a normalized hierarchy structure.

Being a TVF, you can apply any desired `WHERE`, for example `WHERE Lvl=3`, or even use it in a `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
Declare @XML xml='<person><firstname preferred="Annie" nickname="BeBe">Annabelle</firstname><lastname>Smith</lastname></person>'
Select * from [dbo].[udf-XML-Hier](@XML) Order by R1
```

Returns

[image]

**TVF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-XML-Hier](@XML xml)

Returns Table 
As Return

with  cte0 as ( 
                  Select Lvl       = 1
                        ,ID        = Cast(1 as int) 
                        ,Pt        = Cast(NULL as int)
                        ,Element   = x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(150)')
                        ,Attribute = cast('' as varchar(150))
                        ,Value     = x.value('text()[1]','varchar(max)')
                        ,XPath     = cast(concat(x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)'),'[' ,cast(Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 1)) as int),']') as varchar(max))
                        ,Seq       = cast(10000001 as varchar(max))
                        ,AttData   = x.query('.') 
                        ,XMLData   = x.query('*') 
                  From   @XML.nodes('/*') a(x) 
                  Union  All
                  Select Lvl       = p.Lvl + 1 
                        ,ID        = Cast( (Lvl + 1) * 1024 + (Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 1)) * 2) as int ) * 10
                        ,Pt        = p.ID
                        ,Element   = c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(150)')
                        ,Attribute = cast('' as varchar(150))
                        ,Value     = cast( c.value('text()[1]','varchar(max)') as varchar(max) ) 
                        ,XPath     = cast(concat(p.XPath,'/',c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)'),'[',cast(Row_Number() Over(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)') Order By (Select 1)) as int),']') as varchar(max) )
                        ,Seq       = cast(concat(p.Seq,' ',10000000+Cast( (Lvl + 1) * 1024 + (Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 1)) * 2) as int ) * 10) as varchar(max))
                        ,AttData   = c.query('.') 
                        ,XMLData   = c.query('*') 
                  From   cte0 p 
                  Cross  Apply p.XMLData.nodes('*') b(c) 
              )
    , cte1 as (   
                  Select R1 = Row_Number() over (Order By Seq),A.*
                  From  (
                          Select  Lvl,ID,Pt,Element,Attribute,Value,XPath,Seq From cte0
                          Union All
                          Select Lvl       = p.Lvl+1
                                ,ID        = p.ID + Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
                                ,Pt        = p.ID
                                ,Element   = p.Element
                                ,Attribute = x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(150)')
                                ,Value     = x.value('.','varchar(max)')
                                ,XPath     = p.XPath + '/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)')
                                ,Seq       = cast(concat(p.Seq,' ',10000000+p.ID + Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) ) as varchar(max))
                          From   cte0 p 
                          Cross  Apply AttData.nodes('/*/@*') a(x) 
                        ) A 
               )

Select A.R1
      ,R2  = IsNull((Select max(R1) From cte1 Where Seq Like A.Seq+'%'),A.R1)
      ,A.Lvl
      ,A.ID
      ,A.Pt
      ,A.Element
      ,A.Attribute
      ,A.XPath
      ,Title = Replicate('|---',Lvl-1)+Element+IIF(Attribute='','','@'+Attribute)
      ,A.Value
 From  cte1 A

/*
Source: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10495/xquery-lab-58-select-from-xml.aspx
*/
```